# Why Bootstrap does not apply 6:3:3 ration of columns?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this setup in a section, but Bootstrap break the 3rd column into a new line, why?

```html
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="landscapePreviewColumn">
        <img id="landingImageLandscape" src="https://pic.speechifai.tech/1000x1000/F8619E40-A392-4FE1-99BC-8FCCDF81BFA7.jpg">
        <img id="landingImageLandscapeOverlay" src="/img/landing_preview/Desktop2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 pl-3" id="portraitPreviewColumn" style="padding-left:0">
        <img id="landingImagePortrait" src="https://pic.speechifai.tech/57F7B4C0-9A38-4184-874B-707E97EA3977.jpg">
        <img id="landingImagePortraitOverlay" src="/img/landing_preview/Mobile2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 pl-3" id="socialPreviewColumn" style="padding-left:0">
        <img id="landingImageSocial" src="https://pic.speechifai.tech/2FF280BE-DCB3-4235-9B2C-87558D4D26F1.jpg">
        <img id="landingImageSocialOverlay" src="/img/landing_preview/Mobile2.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

---

I removed padding left, but has the same phenomenon.

```
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="landscapePreviewColumn">
        <img id="landingImageLandscape" src="https://pic.speechifai.tech/1000x1000/F8619E40-A392-4FE1-99BC-8FCCDF81BFA7.jpg">
        <img id="landingImageLandscapeOverlay" src="/img/landing_preview/Desktop2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" id="portraitPreviewColumn">
        <img id="landingImagePortrait" src="https://pic.speechifai.tech/57F7B4C0-9A38-4184-874B-707E97EA3977.jpg">
        <img id="landingImagePortraitOverlay" src="/img/landing_preview/Mobile2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" id="socialPreviewColumn">
        <img id="landingImageSocial" src="https://pic.speechifai.tech/2FF280BE-DCB3-4235-9B2C-87558D4D26F1.jpg">
        <img id="landingImageSocialOverlay" src="/img/landing_preview/Mobile2.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but why are you applying the padding left tag, and then setting the element style to be `padding-left: 0` ?

Comment: Removed padding-left, and behaves the same. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
class="img-fluid"
```

to the images.
The documentation says:

> Responsive images Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with
> `.img-fluid`. `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` are applied to the
> image so that it scales with the parent element.

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/

Answer (score 0):

I think, your screen is too small

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#grid-options

try `col-6` `col-3`

Comment: He is using Bootstrap 4 instead of Bootstrap 5.1. Maybe you can change the link to the documentation. I think the breakpoints did not change, but to be sure...

Comment: thank I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the parent container had padding. I set it zero, and then all the 3 item got into one line.